# How to find who hacked my WhatsApp account and sent messages via WhatsApp web

Tags: whatsapp

I want to know I can get the location/IP address of the sender of a WhatsApp message sender which was sent using WhatsApp Web.

Someone has logged into my WhatsApp account and sent messages to my family, and after that deleted those messages. Now I have a big problem, I want to know how to find from where my WhatsApp was logged in to? From which device?

Comment: If your account was hacked, you need to contact WhatsApp Inc or Facebook (who own WhatsApp). Contact them ASAP, they might still have logs. Give them your username, and the time of the event, as precisely as you can. (Be sure to add the timezone you're using, to help them retrieve the relevant logs). Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

All WhatsApp messages are first sent to WhatsApp's own servers and *then* forwarded to the recipient. Your IP address will not be sent along to the final recipient (but it will certainly be recorded and stored on the WhatsApp servers). As an end user you can neither [obtain it from a regular message](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98050/does-whatsapp-disclose-the-senders-ip-address) nor from one sent over the web messenger interface.

The obvious exception are of course official requests by a law enforcement authority. Despite end-to-end encryption WhatsApp is not an *anonymizing* communication tool.