# Can a VPN hide my IP on Whatsapp?

Tags: vpn, whatsapp

My IP can be seen by a Whatsapp contact using the netstat command. Can a VPN hide my real IP to them? Or their netstat will still show my real IP?

Comment: *"My IP can be seen by a Whatsapp contact using the netstat command."* - are you sure? I don't think so. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98050/does-whatsapp-disclose-the-senders-ip-address

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does WhatsApp disclose the sender's IP address?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98050/does-whatsapp-disclose-the-senders-ip-address)

Answer (score 2):

When messaging, WhatsApp contacts cannot see your IP address. WhatsApp itself can, of course. When making VoIP calls using WhatsApp, your IP [might be visible](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98050/does-whatsapp-disclose-the-senders-ip-address) to the contact.

Yes, you could in theory hide this using a VPN. You just have to ensure your VPN is configured correctly, and all internet communication on your phone is relayed through the VPN (before installing WhatsApp).

Answer (score 1):

> Can a VPN hide my IP on Whatsapp?

That's what a VPN does, so yes.